# Does Firebase Email and Password authentication have any security configuration options?

Tags: security, authentication, firebase, firebase-security

While sniffing the Firebase traffic, I have seen that a code is passed to the auth server so that it always returns a 200 status code. This shows that there is some level of optional security at some level in the authentication protocol.

Is there a way to cause Firebase authentication to fail with an identical error message when the user enters a non-existent email address as when they enter the wrong password?

[The `INVALID_USER` status code](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-full-error) gives me concern about the potential for a [user enumeration attack](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_User_Enumeration_and_Guessable_User_Account_(OWASP-AT-002)), in a case where my application has become compromised via script injection.

Information on how to more securely lock down the Firebase auth protocol, and/or some sort of statement about smart rate limiting (somehow distributed attack immune?) being applied would probably go a long way to assuring me that Firebase's built-in email and password auth is indeed secure (assuming Firebase rules are set up correctly, certs aren't compromised on the client, etc).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(Firebase employee) For now, the answer is no: you can't control the status codes reported to the client.

The good news is that an enumeration attack would be fairly difficult, as we throttle requests by origin to mitigate any brute force approaches.