# Firebase user enumeration attack

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am looking for more details regarding Firebase protection against brute force password guessing.

In this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32840169/does-firebase-email-and-password-authentication-have-any-security-configuration), Kato says "we throttle requests by origin to mitigate any brute force approaches", can any more info be given ? especially:

- when does throttling kicks in and if at any point the client is completely blocked for a certain time etc ?
- can we have a way in the security rules to specify a number of failed attempts after which the client will be locked out for a certain amount of time ?

I want to switch to a digit only 'numpad' password on my app and am worried an enumeration attack. I need to determine the minimum number of digits to make passwords safe.

Thanks!

Comment: *firebaser here* We do not disclose such information in public documentation or fora. If you have a specific problem, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting. If you'd like to request a specific change to a feature (or a new feature), fill out [this feature request form](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Frank answered in the comments, so I'm just adding two additional information that might be useful:

- Firebase prevents using passwords that have less than 6 characters (see [FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException))
- A specific error code (ERROR_TOO_MANY_REQUESTS) is thrown when unusual activity is detected on a specific device. So you could easily make some tests to see how fast the error is triggered. I just did, and 3-4 incorrect password attempts triggered the error and blocked the requests from my device.

From the doc:
[auth/too-many-requests](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Error)
*Thrown if requests are blocked from a device due to unusual activity. Trying again after some delay would unblock.*